# ¿Por qué se congela DOSbox al ejecutar código?

Tags: ensamblador

Estoy haciendo un código para sumar 2 números, pero al ejecutarlo se congela DOSbox.

```
073F:0100 mov ax,0002;
073F:0103 mov bx,0004;
073F:0106 add ax,bx;
073F:0108 int 21;
073F:010A
```

Al presionar `-g` es cuando ya no responde el programa y no sé qué hacer, soy nuevo en lenguaje ensamblador.

Comment: Veo que, efectivamente, sumas dos número ... **y llamas a una interrupción**. ¿ Cabría la posibilidad de que tu problema no fuera la suma, sino una llamada a una interrupción con argumentos incorrectos ?

Comment: La verdad no tengo idea, soy un total principiante a esto y por eso estaba intentando agarrarle la práctica haciendo códigos sencillos pero no puedo por este mismo problema. ¿Qué es lo que sugieres?